# When and why does Scala code needs to be on a method called main inside an object?

Tags: scala, object, intellij-idea, methods

I realized that when I code some script in scala and compile and run it from the terminal, I need to put it on a main method inside a object. But when a run it inside Intellij IDEA that's not needed. Why is that? Why do some people extend App on the global object?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16993075/9204 (other answers there may help as well).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The difference between scala script and application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674327/the-difference-between-scala-script-and-application)

Answer (score 0):

In Scala there are two ways to create a runnable main class.

One is using the main method in an object:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

A slightly shorter version is extending the `App` trait and writing the code directly into the object body:

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello, world!")
}
```

Both of these work irrespective of whether you're using IntelliJ.

See also: https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/your-first-lines-of-scala.html